# Is there Octave's equivalent for iPython's "!"

Tags: octave

For example,

`!vim`

in iPython opens vim. Is there such a thing in Octave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might work `system("vim");`

If you want the interactivity of calling something inside of Octave and interactivity with it directly try `exec("vim")` instead.

See [Controlling Subprocesses](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Controlling-Subprocesses.html#doc%2ddos) for more examples.

Otherwise you can either combine calls to `system`, `fork` and `exec` or extend octave with Python/iPython or C++.

Comment: `system vim file.m` returns `Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal`.

Comment: `exec vim file.m` opens the file but upon `:q` return to the shell prompt. (Also explained in Appleman's link.)

Comment: After `fork`, I can hardly type letters in prompt.(The letter appears once in a while.)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to run another process then , the already suggested `system()` or `exec()` should work.

However, if you plan on using this to simply open up a text editor and edit an Octave file, set the value of EDITOR with `EDITOR ("vim")` (you can add this to your `.octaverc` file) and then use `edit (foo)` to open up the foo function on the text editor.